# Is there a way to have 2 package.json files, one for publishing and one for the project itself?

Tags: npm

What I want to achieve is to have 2 folders, one containing the source code(modules, controllers, service classes, etc.) and one folder containing DTO classes. The `pkg` folder would be what would be provided if the project is set as a dependency in another project. The file structure goes as such:

```
pkg
│  └── package files . . .
src
│  └── project files . . .
├── package.pkg.json
└── package.src.json
```

```json
// package.pkg.json
{
  "name": "@example/service-a"
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "files": [
    "dist/pkg"
  ],
  "main": "dist/pkg/index.js",
  "types": "dist/pkg/index.d.ts"
}
```

```json
// package.src.json
{
  "name": "@example/service-a"
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/src/main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "some-dependency": "1.0.0",
    "another-dependency": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

The main reason I want to separate the `package.json` into two is because when the service is downloaded as a package it also install the production dependencies of the service.

If we're able to do this then, for example, if we had service A and service B, where B would request some information from service A, there wouldn't be a conjoining dependency which would expose what service A could provide to service B.

Is there a way to achieve this?